# Domain Technicality

Tags: geometry, functions

If $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1},$ then what is the domain of $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$? I know that the resultant function is $h(x)=x^3+x^2,$ but is there a hole in the graph of $h(x)$ at $(-1,0)$ to signify that $-1$ is not in the domain of $g(x)$?

Comment: You performed the polynomial division incorrectly.  When you divide a quadratic polynomial by a linear polynomial, the result is a linear polynomial plus the remainder term.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I divided the quadratic by $1$ divided by a linear polynomial, so the result is a quadratic times a linear, which is a cubic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you are to find the domain of the form $f(x)/g(x)$, the principle is to make it make sense. So in the first place both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must make sense, and in the second, you have to check that $g(x)\ne0$ if necessary.

Note also that you cannot casually simplify the expression into $f(x)\cdot 1/g(x)$ because to make such a simplification you must ensure the validity of $g(x)$ first. What's the point of a simplification when $g(x)$ itself doesn't make sense? Casual simplification will probably hide some "holes" in the domain.

Another impressive example, try to find the domain of 
$$F(x)=\ln\left(\frac1x\right)+\ln(x)$$
It is then obvious that you are never supposed to conclude that it's a constant function with domain $\Bbb R$ by simplifying $F(x)$ into $\ln1$

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right, and because of that hole we'd say the domain is all real numbers (assuming a real-valued function) with the exclusion of $x = -1$.

Put more formally the domain is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ne -1 \}$.

Another way to think about it is to consider under what scenario(s) you are allowed to obtain your polynomial whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$, well it is precisely that case (or cases) for which $x \ne -1$.